# Safe-way to remount partitions

Tags: fstab

I currently have mounts that look like this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        16G  7.7G  7.3G  52% /
/dev/sdb2       237G   20G  207G   9% /var/www
/dev/sdb1        16G  7.5G  7.4G  51% /var/lib/jenkins
```

Unfortunately, I don't have enough room on `/dev/sdb1`.  I'd like to move things around to be like this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        16G  7.7G  7.3G  52% /
/dev/sdb2       237G   27G  200G  11% /var
```

Is it too naive to simply script this pseudo code?

```
systemctl stop apache2 jenkins

for each dir in /var:
  if dir is 'www':
     mv /var/www/* /var/www/www/
     continue
  mv dir /var/www/

mv /var/lib/jenkins /var/www/lib/jenkins

sed -i 's|/var/www|/var|' /etc/fstab
sed -i 'd|/var/lib/jenkins|' /etc/fstab

reboot
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handling of `/var/www` and `/var/lib/jenkins` seems OK, but you’ve missed one important part of the exercise: you need to move anything in `/var`, stored on `/`, into the new `/var`.

To do that reliably, you’ll need to stop anything currently using `/var`. I suspect the easiest way to do that will be to reboot to a live environment.